# React Router v6 with React 18 and Typescript - Error Message in console "Uncaught TypeError: Converting curcular structure to JSON"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

When using the latest of react-router-dom (v6.9.0) I keep getting an error message in the console:

[image: [Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scTwg.jpg)]

I have tried multiple ways to setup the router but no matter what I do it still happens. Sometimes the error is only visible in the console, and sometimes if I refresh the screen its also visible in the browser.

I created this test project as a way to demonstrate the issue: https://github.com/charlenecoffman/testingsomething

Here is what the index.tsx looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Here is what the App.tsx has:

```
import './App.css';
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import AboutPage from './pages/About';
import HomePage from './pages/Home';

function App() {
  return (    
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="about" element={<AboutPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is what the package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "testingsomething",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.21",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.29",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried installing a few version of react router. I have looked over this tutorial: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial - and tried some of what its suggesting. But I cannot tell what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The console error seems to imply there's an issue in some chrome extension code. Nothing in your shared code snippet or repo appears to be related to the error from what I can tell. Try disabling the extensions and turn them on 1-by-1 until you find the bad one, and leave that one disabled so you can continue app development.

Comment: You are a GENIUS! [This is the culprit](https://ibb.co/R0YcCXt)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)